# Trying to change a XML node with no success

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I'm trying to change a the value for the `model` atribute from the following `.xml` file.

```
<MTConnectDevices xmlns="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectDevices:1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectDevices:1.1 http://www.mtconnect.org/schemas/MTConnectDevices_1.1.xsd">
  <Header version="1.1" sender="Company MTConnect Instance" creationTime="2010-08-26T19:00:47-07:00" instanceId="2" bufferSize="131072" />
  <Devices>
    <Device name="XX" iso841Class="1" uuid="000" id="id1001">
      <Description manufacturer="name" serialNumber="Serial Number" model="UNDEFINED">
      </Description>
```

This is what I've tried but it's not working as it's not changing the value for `model`.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(mypath);
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
        var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:MTConnectDevices/ns:Header/ns:Devices/ns:Device/ns:Description", nsmgr);
        node.Attributes["model"].Value = "changed";
        xmlDoc.Save(mypath);
```

Can anyone give me a hand and tell me how to fix this?

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: It's not changing the value.

Comment: Have you inspected the state of `node` in the debugger, or is it just that the value in the file isn't being updated? Does changing `/MTConnectDevices` to `//MTConnectDevices` make any difference?

Comment: On the `node.Attributes["model"].Value = "newvalue";` Im getting a `NullReferenceException` . This means it's not fetching the node correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of the MTConnect stream itself? If so, that defeats the purpose of MTConnect. Regardless, if you're still interested in MTConnect, I'd recommend following http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80667/internet-of-things so there's a better place to post questions about MTConnect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xml contains namespaces, so you have to use them while retrieving node.

It can be done something like this:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:MTConnectDevices/ns:Devices/ns:Device/ns:Description", nsmgr);
```

Comment: When I try to change the node using `node.Attributes["model"].Value = "newvalue";` im getting a `NullReferenceException` . This means it's not fetching the node correctly?

Comment: @Borja This means either node can't be found by specified path (so it is null) or node found, but it has no `model` attribute. Have you provided relevant xml? I'm not getting any exceptions on xml you've provided (using modified path including Header), and model attribute is being updated.

Comment: I know where's the problem. It's on the URL's from the `MTConnectDevices` atributes:  `<MTConnectDevices test="" xmlns="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectDevices:1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectDevices:1.1 http://www.mtconnect.org/schemas/MTConnectDevices_1.1.xsd">` 

Testing, if I remove the URL's and leave only the `test` attribute everything works fine and the `test` attribute changes perfectly. `<MTConnectDevices test="" >` Any ideas of what's happening?

Comment: @Borja See update. The fact that your xml has namespaces is essential, it was better not to omit this fact in question.

Comment: Thanks for the update Andy. Now I'm having the same `NullReferenceException` on the `nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);` value. Any ideas?

Comment: @Borja Can you use the debugger to determine what exactly null in this line? is it xmlDoc, is it xmlDoc.DocumentElement or anything else? Where exactly have you placed this code (I hope, after loading document to xmlDoc)? Update your question with relevant xml and code, otherwise it's hard to say what's wrong on your side.

Comment: Ignore the last comment. After copying and pasting I removed the `xmlDoc.Load(mypath);` line unintentionally so it was not loading correctly. Anyways, I'm still getting the same error `NullReferenceException` on the same line `node.Attributes["model"].Value = "changed";` . I upadted the solution with the code and a proper version of the `.xml`. Thanks in advance. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Solved! I fixed it by removing the `Header` from the path `var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:MTConnectDevices/ns:Devices/ns:Device/ns:Description", nsmgr);` Please, update your answer so I can accept it. Cheers!

Comment: @Borja oh... seeing your **actual** xml it's clearly evident that porblem was only in namespaces since `Header` tag is self-closed. I will update my answer and remove misleading part, but please - post relevant information to avoid confusion....

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks a lot for your help, Andy.